# Android Service with auth dependency design approach

Tags: android, authentication, android-service

I am wondering what would be a good architecture design for a `Service` that runs even if the app is killed by the system (need to run indefinitely) and, that needs the user to be authenticated to communicate with a backend.

For instance, an app to prompts you to sign in and, while authenticated, the `Service` will notify your current location to the server. Auto login with saved credentials might be desired in this scenario.

I foresee a couple of design decisions that might be important:

- Who's in charge of the authentication?
- Who's in charge of the communication with the backend? In the example: notify the current user location.
- If user changes his password out of the app (in a Website for instance) and the `Service` is not aware of, it's absolutely acceptable. But, when signing in again via app it should update its credentials and run normally again.

I have thought in these solutions, but might be not ideal:

1. All the server communication placed in the app and the `Service` wakes up the app when necessary using `AlarmManager` & `BroadcastReceiver`.
2. Place the server communication (in example, location notification) in the `Service` and notify about credentials from the app when credentials renewed (token, whatever,... trying to be a bit auth backend implementation agnostic).
3. Implement an `Account` in [`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) and keep both components kind of independent. `Service` relies on `AccountManager`, so doesn't need to deal with authentication and can do its work by its own.

Advantages and inconveniences of the suggested solutions? Any other approach?

In (1), I do see the problem of  `WakeLock` happening too often (battery drain) if the communication with the backend is intense. (3) seems to be more isolated, but I have no experience with it and don't know the drawbacks.